# Supabase postgres cron job not working special case

Tags: postgresql, jobs, scheduled-tasks, cron

I'm having the problem, while insering a row using rpc through the nodejs library, with user **service_role**.

i gave permission to all roles. Without exception.

And for **service_role** I even gave it all privileges in the whole database just for the sake of testing.

launching the cron from the dashboard editor. And after giving the permission to **postgres** as above. And as per this [thread](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/1703)
It worked. The cron worked just right.

But then when i do it through **service_role**. From nodejs rpc insert. Which trigger a trigger procedure. Which run all right.

I made a command to ccheck which insert in a log table I created. In mean time, the job is added to the jobs table. And being active.

However no command run. (the mentioned user I gave him the privileges for cron. But then after I gave him even access to all. Nothing works.)

Any ideas or pointing.

Here my trigger function

[image]

The schedule command is temporal I took from the one that worked on the dashboard to make sure ..?

How can this be explained ? Any ideas or points ? Anything may be special about supabase ? May be the **service_role** user have some restriction ??? or . i'm just out of clues hhh

( an official ref: https://supabase.io/blog/2021/03/05/postgres-as-a-cron-server )

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem!

You can check that in those threads where i asked! And shared many elements!

https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/1703

https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/479

### how to check the cron job run, and log

From the official articles (article about [cron job](https://supabase.io/blog/2021/03/05/postgres-as-a-cron-server))

[image]

Check the cron.job_run_details! It contain every attempted command execution.

```sql
select * from cron.job_run_details;
```

[image]

Checking the table as mentioned on the article! i found out that the command execution is failing! Because the **connection failed**!

I made the user a super user temporally! But then it seems not the thing!
And it's something that require Db Authentication config!

[citusdata/pg_cron#66](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/issues/66)

I was inserting a row from nodejs (service_role)! Which trigger a function that schedule the cron! The cron schedule all right and work! Commands only fail!

I mostly tried everything! Then i considered creating a new user!

### Solution

I ended up **creating a total new user** (role)! **With it's password!** And used that for the external connection! I gave the new user the **necessary priveleges**! And **all worked well**!

(Using service_role was problematic! Even by giving it super user privileges! it didn't work! And fail by a 'connection failed' error!